# How to fix "Singleton array array(0) cannot be considered a valid collection."

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, keras, librosa

I'm trying to create a .npy file by splitting the arrays into train and test  subsets, but while trying to do that, I am facing with this error which is pointing to validation.py and _split.py in Sklearn folder. I am using python 3.6.7

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import utils
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical

DATA_PATH = "./Angry/"
X=0
y=0
split_ratio=0.6
random_state=42

def get_train_test():
    labels, indices, _ = get_labels(DATA_PATH)

    # Getting first arrays
    X= np.load(labels[0] + '.npy')
    y= np.zeros(X.shape[0])

    # Append all of the dataset into one single array, same goes for y
    for i, label in enumerate(labels[1:]):
        x = np.load(label + '.npy')
        X = np.vstack((X, x))
        y = np.append(y, np.full(x.shape[0], fill_value= (i + 1)))

    assert X.shape[0] == len(y)

    return train_test_split(X, y, test_size= (1 - split_ratio), random_state=random_state, shuffle=True)

def wav2mfcc(file_path, max_pad_len=11):
    wave, sr = librosa.load(file_path, mono=True, sr=None)
    wave = wave[::3]
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(wave, sr=16000)
    pad_width = max_pad_len - mfcc.shape[1]
    mfcc = np.pad(mfcc, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)),mode='constant')
    return mfcc

def get_labels(path=DATA_PATH):
    labels = os.listdir(path)
    label_indices = np.arange(0, len(labels))
    return labels, label_indices, to_categorical(label_indices)

def save_data_to_array(path=DATA_PATH, max_pad_len=11):
    labels, _, _ = get_labels(path)
    for label in labels:
        # Init mfcc vectors
        mfcc_vectors = []
        wavfiles = [path + label + '/' + wavfile for wavfile in os.listdir(path + '/' + label)]

        for wavfile in wavfiles:
            mfcc = wav2mfcc(wavfile, max_pad_len=max_pad_len)
            mfcc_vectors.append(mfcc)
    np.save(label + '.npy', mfcc_vectors)

if __name__=='__main__':
    feature_dim_2 = 11

    # Save data to array file first
    save_data_to_array(max_len=feature_dim_2)

    # # Loading train set and test set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = get_train_test()

    # # Feature dimension
    feature_dim_1 = 20
    channel = 1
    epochs = 50
    batch_size = 100
    verbose = 1
    num_classes = 3

    # Reshaping to perform 2D convolution
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_dim_1,feature_dim_2, channel)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_dim_1, feature_dim_2, channel)
    y_train_hot = to_categorical(y_train) 
    y_test_hot = to_categorical(y_test)
```

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> cell_name in async-def-wrapper()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn
> /model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
>
>      2182         test_size = 0.25
>
>      2183 
>
> -->  2184     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
>
>      2185 
>
>      2186     if shuffle is False:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> ```
>
> in indexable(*iterables)
>
> ```
>     258     """Make arrays indexable for cross-validation.
>
>     259 
>
> --> 260     Checks consistent length, passes through None, and ensures that everything
>
>     261     can be indexed by converting sparse matrices to csr and converting
>
>     262     non-interable objects to arrays.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> ```
>
> in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
>
> ```
>     229             memory = Memory(cachedir=memory, verbose=0)
>
>     230         else:
>
> --> 231             memory = Memory(location=memory, verbose=0)
>
>     232     elif not hasattr(memory, 'cache'):
>
>     233         raise ValueError("'memory' should be None, a string or have the same"
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> ```
>
> in (.0)
>
> ```
>     229             memory = Memory(cachedir=memory, verbose=0)
>
>     230         else:
>
> --> 231             memory = Memory(location=memory, verbose=0)
>
>     232     elif not hasattr(memory, 'cache'):
>
>     233         raise ValueError("'memory' should be None, a string or have the same"
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> ```
>
> in _num_samples(x)
>
> ```
>     140             raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
>
>     141                             " a valid collection." % x)
>
> --> 142         return x.shape[0]
>
>     143     else:
>
>     144         return len(x)
>
> TypeError: Singleton array array(0) cannot be considered a valid collection.
> ```